# ASP.NET Trying to create a webpage that reads from data source (XLS, XLSX) to dynamically display selected data

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net, excel

Thank you in advance,

I am trying to create a web page that lets other users who know nothing about programming to edit the content that is displayed. I want them to fill in the blanks on an excel spreadsheet for example and then my webpage will grab the data from that block and print it out in html format. Let me give you an example:

```
<h1> <% =xlSheet1.Cells.Item(3,2) %> <h1>
<p> <% =xlSheet1.Cells.Item(10,10) %> <p>
```

I have looked all over the web and I cannot find anything that is up to date and similar with what I am trying to accomplish and this is a work project so any quick help would be greatly appreciated. Please keep in mind that I am new to ASP.NET, C# and VB but I am doing my best to learn what I can.

`I am working in Visual Studio 2015`

Thanks again!

Comment: Okay so I decided to explore my options outside of asp.net and I found that using Excel Online I can actually embed a dynamic sheet into my website and select the ranges that I need. The only issue is that the API is an iframe that displays things I dont want people to see (give feedback to microsoft, view full sized worksheet). Anyone know of a way to style it just like a paragraph element instead of an iframe chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going another route. Classic-ASP and VB.NET. 
Everything works great now.